# Integer Array in TextView

Tags: java, android, math, error-handling, crash

I want to display even numbers from 0 to 50 in a text view, when button is clicked.

```
package com.example.a206_multithreading_assignment;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView even;
    Button result;

    int[] numbers = new int[50];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        even = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.even);
        result = (Button)findViewById(R.id.result);


        result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                for (int j=0 ; j<50 ; j++)
                {
                    if (j%2 == 0) {
                        even.setText(numbers[j]);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my code. My app got crash at run time.

I searched alot but find information about string arrays not related to integer arrays.
I will be thankful, If my issue got resolved.

Comment: numbers array  does not contain any value.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this `even.setText(numbers[j].toString())`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your number array has any values. I think your code would be fine if you fixed that.

Comment: for (int i=0 ; i<50 ; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = i;
        }                                                                                                                                                      I added this initializtion, but still get error

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I see an extra parenthesis down at the bottom, maybe that's causing the error and also can you show us the error for extra clarification?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the array is initialized to 0.

First, you need to fill this array with your values.

In your case j% 2 == 0 always returns false

Comment: for (int i=0 ; i<50 ; i++) { numbers[i] = i; } I added this initializtion, but still get error

Comment: Use even.setText(Integer.toString(numbers[j]))

Comment: There are two overloads of this method in the TextView for setText. And so it turns out that by passing the number, the method is called that takes the id of the string resource. And so you get Runtime error